# Варианты создания GUI в windows на C++

Tags: c++, windows, gui

Начал недавно изучать C++ на windows, и сейчас мне очень интересно узнать от опытных людей - какие способы создания графического пользовательского интерфейса актуальны, несложны и не требуют скачивания лишнего софта? Знаю о существовании Qt, но мне это не подходит. (Кроссплатформенность неважна, моя цель - windows)

Comment: хз почему Qt не подходит, эта самая топовая библиотека для UI. Ну раз так то Visual Studio Windows form

Comment: а вообще если ты недавно начал изучать то забей на это и учи основы

Comment: есть еще вариант это SFML, но она как по мне для игр

Comment: так же есть встроенная библиотека graphics.h

Comment: @Lofectr. *"встроенная"* Угу, в Turbo C++ встроенная. :Р

Comment: @Lofectr. windows form? это который .net framework но на c++?

Comment: @wrench29 да, там я не знаю как работает(не интересовался, я вообще VS не люблю), но оно работает

Comment: Дикий повтор, отвечали 1000000 раз - поищите тут или на en обзор плюсовых гуевых библиотек

Comment: изучайте: https://philippegroarke.com/posts/2018/c++_ui_solutions/

Comment: @Croessmah - спасибо за ссылку, узнал из неё, что появился BoostGui, а отдельные библиотеки "доставляют" своим названием: morda

Answer (score 1):

ИМХО. Qt - это не только кроссплатформенность, но и GUI. Причём есть несколько вариантов создания интерфейсов. Последняя продвигаемая ими идеология - это Qt Quick + QML. Qt в сердце моем и для Windows и для Linux и для Андроида.

Comment: раз уж все так настаивают на qt - можете дать хороший, на ваш взгляд, туториал по qt (опен сорс версии)? И ооооочень хотелось бы увидеть полный процесс, от установки софта до компиляции в .exe и запуска

Comment: @wrench29 Да вы скачайте QtCreator и откройте вкладку Help. Там этих туториалов. Это же Qt - у них лучшая документация что я видел. Там и просто доки, и видео, и небольшие примеры. Не знаете что за класс - поставили на него курсор, нажали F1 - открылась страница с докой на него. Там же в QtCreator

Comment: @wrench29 Читайте Макса Шлее. Это учебник #1. Как только выходит новая версия Qt тут же появляется новая версия его книги. Просмотрите vlog на ютубе от voidrealms, подборка уроков называется c++ Qt Programming. Там действительно все начинается с установки софта.

Comment: а можете рассказать что такое Qt Quick + QML

Comment: @Lofectr Google в помощь. Всё равно в паре предложений не рассказать. QML - это язык разметки. Qt Quick - технология интерфейсов. При такой идеологии происходит чёткое разделение поведения GUI и ядра программы. GUI описывается с использованием QML со вставкой кусков кода на Javascript-подобном языке. При этом к основному коду имеется доступ через систему сигналов-слотов.

Comment: Аааа типо QML XML

Comment: @Lofectr Именно так, правда общего у QML и XML только последние 2 буквы = meta language.

Answer (score 1):

Qt если хочешь сделать u и при этом не писать километр кода. SFML для gui так се затея. Писал, пытался, ну такое)) а в qt помимо u есть много интересных и нужных библиотек.